# Handling several exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception

Consider the following Java code:

```
try{

    // do something
    // this piece of code throws several checked exceptions.

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

The code in `try` block throws several checked exceptions. All I want to do is to log a message when an exception occurs (with some custom message strings). I.e. my exception handling logic is same for *all exceptions*.

I feel the above code dosn't look good (more LOC and reduced readability).

**Is there any better ways to handle such cases?**

The following solution is not a best practice, so not recommended (by Check style).

```
try{
    // do something very bad
} catch (Exception e) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

Comment: Use Java 7 where you can aggregate exceptions. Catching `Exception` is not bad per se, handling all `Exception` instances as equal is.

Comment: You should not blindly follow best practices. Every best practice has counterexamples. In this case I think using a single general catch could be justified if you are sure you won't be easily changing exception handling.

Comment: See the marco approach. You solve the problem with a good practice.... If you only catch Exception, you mask the non-checked exceptions.

This isn't a counterexample to do best practices.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Java 6 you don't have any option much more appealing than what you have already suggested.

But Java 7 has a [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) statement that you can use:

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | IOException exception) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I feel in your case the second option will do just fine. There's no need to overcomplicate your code if exception handling is the same for every case.

Comment: This way, you are masking all the non-checked exceptions. God cries when you do that kind of things.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7, there is a new and excellent solution: you can write:

```
try{

    // do something
    // this piece of code throws several checked exceptions.

} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    handleException(e);
} catch ...
```

In older Java versions, catching common subclasses -- `Exception` being one case of this -- is really not a bad idea. It's bad to *always* do it without consideration, but it's OK to do it if you've thought about it and chosen it as the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to do, with Java 6 or lesser.

With java 7, you can do something like this:

```
catch(InstantiationException | IOException | NoSuchFieldException exception) {
        // handle our problems here.
}
```

In java 6, another "bad practice" (but maybe useful for you) can be:

```
catch (Exception e) {
   if(! e instanceof RuntimeException) // Only non-checked exceptions!
       throw e;
   handleException(e) // All checked exception.
}
```

The problem: You are using instanceof. But your code looks better...

Answer (score 3):

This is another example of how checked exceptions make the life of Java programmers miserable. Just because a piece of code can, among others, throw checked exceptions, that specific piece of code is in all probability **not** the place where you want to handle them. If your app is well-designed, you already have a central place, an *exception barrier*, where you handle (log) your exceptions. If that is the case, then you should just wrap all those exceptions into a `RuntimeException` and pass them on towards the barrier. In that case this is the handling code:

```
try {
  // do stuff
} catch (RuntimeException e) { 
  throw e; 
} catch (Exception e) { 
  throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you guys think about this solution?

```
try {
    // some code that might throw an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof RuntimeException){
        throw (RuntimeException) e;
    }
    // log exception
}
```

**Pros:**

1. Less code, can keep same exception handling logic for all **checked exceptions**.
2. Does not handle run time exceptions and Errors. Catches them but throws them back.

**Cons:**

1. Do not confirm to the *best practice* check, as it still catches Exception. (but the scenarios of catching run time exceptions are taken care, though the check style might fail.)
2. Any possible side effects for downcasting to *RuntimeException*?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the guys in Java 7 team heard your complains :-) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you meant to do this:

```
try{
    // do something very bad
} catch (Throwable e) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

This catches not only all exceptions, but also errors - everything that might be thrown inside the try/catch block.

Catching all exceptions and letting all errors pass is rarely the right thing to do but catching a long list of arbitrarily chosen unrelated exceptions is even less likely the right thing to do.

Your list of exceptions looks rather suspicious. I.e. why do you catch IllegalArgumentException  but not also NullPointerException or ClassCastException which are semantically at a similar level. And you seem to be using Reflection in conjunction with IO, so you might also have to deal with NoClassDefFoundError, ExceptionInInitializerError and other errors. And what about StackOverflowError or even OutOfMemoryError ...

Comment: the exceptions I used is just for example to explain the scenario. Those are not the 'actual' exceptions I'm looking from my code.